# SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 24 invalid identifier Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' Invalid identifier

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting Below error while running the procedure in snowflake

> **Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 6 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 24 invalid identifier 'I.DEPTNO'**

```
create table emp(empid number, ename varchar2(20), deptno number);

insert into emp values
   (1,'John',10),
   (2,'Alex',20),
   (3,'Mick',20);

create table dept(deptno number, dname varchar2(20));

insert into dept values
   (10,'Sales'),
   (20,'HR');

create table emp2 as select * from emp limit 0;
```

```
create or replace procedure emp_dept_proc()
returns varchar(200)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  c1 cursor for select empid,ename,deptno from emp where deptno=20;

begin
  for i in c1 do
    insert into emp2 (empid , ename ,deptno)

      select empid,ename,deptno
      from emp where deptno = i.deptno;
  end for;
end;
$$
```

```
call emp_dept_proc();
```

[image]

Comment: Errors aside, why would you perform single line inserts like this? `INSERT INTO emp2 (empid, ename, depatno) SELECT empid, ename, deptno FROM emp WHERE deptno = 20;` would suffice without all the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

So not super happy with the work around but using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html) we can build the SQL we want to use:

```
create or replace procedure emp_dept_proc()
returns varchar(200)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  c1 cursor for select empid,ename,deptno from emp where deptno=20;
begin
  for i in c1 do
    execute immediate 'insert into emp2 (empid , ename ,deptno)
      select empid,ename,deptno
      from emp where deptno = ' || i.deptno;
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

```
truncate emp2;
```

```
call emp_dept_proc();
select * from emp2;
```

| EMPID | ENAME | DEPTNO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | 20 |
| 3 | Mick | 20 |
| 2 | Alex | 20 |
| 3 | Mick | 20 |

you are getting 4 rows because you are inserting "all match departments to 20" x 2

### The build the dynamic SQL version:

only slightly different but if you have complex SQL to build, this is more or less how I would do it:

```
create or replace procedure emp_dept_proc()
returns varchar(200)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  c1 cursor for select empid,ename,deptno from emp where deptno = 20;
begin
  for i in c1 do
    let _sql varchar := 'insert into emp2 (empid , ename ,deptno) select empid, ename, deptno from emp where deptno = ' || i.deptno;
    execute immediate _sql;
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

### The create new variables version:

so it works if your are using single named variables:

```
create or replace procedure emp_dept_proc()
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
declare
  c1 cursor for select empid, ename, deptno from emp where deptno = 20;
  deptno number;
begin
  for i in c1 do
    deptno := i.deptno;
    insert into emp2 (empid, ename, deptno)
      select empid, ename, deptno 
      from emp 
      where deptno = :deptno;
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay ..This is just an example . I need to use the cursor as we use in PL/SQL. I am converting PL/SQL Code to snowflake. so is there any other way to do without execute immediate ?

Comment: found the work around to use new variable to get around what seems a parser bug. I would recommend report that to support.

Comment: Thanks for your support . yes its seems to be parsing bug. i will raise same with snowflake support team

Comment: Hi Simeon , while running the above mentioned query i am facing performance issue. cursor is returning 10000 records and i have only access of small warehouse. can you please advice.

Comment: is bulk collect support Snowflake ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are meaning. Would I ever run the any of the example SQL as it is written. NO is the worst way to insert large number of rows.. But your question was not "is this wise" or "will it scale", you asked "this madness does not work". I ASSUMED the code was a toy example, and not how it looks.